# How accurate is opencv cameraCalibration method?

Tags: iphone, opencv, camera, calibration

I'm trying to calibrate iPhone camera using chessboard in OpenCV. I took 10 pictures of the chessboard for each camera with different angles and position and get corners with findChessboardCorners
cornerSubPix
Corners were detected correctly and I run calibrateCamera. Which returned 1.61 and 1.91 for each camera respectfully.

This is camera matrix and distCoefficients for the first camera:

```
3 3
1908.264124 0.000000 731.907383 
0.000000 1905.905573 1056.741746 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 
5
0.085256 -0.224177 -0.003808 -0.011916 0.225885
```

This is camera matrix and distCoefficients for the second camera:

```
3 3
1887.450093 0.000000 729.742424 
0.000000 1883.005955 1066.861173 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 
5
0.067340 -0.106684 -0.002520 -0.013685 0.096439
```

iPhones are absolutely the same, so I guess the intrinsic parameters also should be the same. But distortion parameters could vary from device to device. Is it normal that camera matrices are so different.

Moreoever. I repeated the experiment with different images and same camera and tis is what I got:

Returned values are 3.08 and 2.96 respectively.

This is camera matrix and distCoefficients for the first camera:

```
3 3
1874.278119 0.000000 773.259310 
0.000000 1875.865618 1076.424783 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 
5
0.123774 -0.919622 0.000288 -0.013419 0.945573
```

This is camera matrix and distCoefficients for the second camera:

```
3 3
1942.557567 0.000000 751.467965 
0.000000 1946.888384 1094.068254 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 
5
0.155755 -1.063302 0.008551 -0.014473 1.079105
```

Is this error acceptable? Is it what I should expect normally?

Comment: how accurate is your calibration pattern detection? did you use exactly the same focus distance?

Comment: so you get the same results on calubrating the same camera over and over?

Comment: @Micka, yes the same focal distance... iPhone doesn't change its focal length right? It's not the same results, results vary, but I'm not sure if this variance is within acceptable error

Comment: is the difference on calibrating the same camera over and over similar to the difference between cameras?

Comment: @Micka, Calibrating on same set of images gives exactly the same results. Differences are not the same. I posted all the results in my original post.

Comment: you should obviously use different images to calibrate the same camera again. The idea is to find out whether the "error" is from slightly different camera setup or from calibration algorithm. If you get very equal results on calibrating the same camera (with different images), the algorithm probably is not so error prone. If you get varying results and they are within the range of the difference to the 2nd camera, probably both cameras' intrinsics are very equal. If results differ slightly but are big between cameras, algorithm has low error but cameras differ.

Comment: maybe compute statistical mean and variance for a single cam? Btw. afaik camera focus does influence the camera intrinsics, but not as much as an optical zoom would do.

Comment: @Micka. Yes I know, onm different set of images, calibration results are different. Too different. Like for the first set of images my principal point is: 731.907383 1056.741746. On the second set of images, with the same camera: 773.259310 1076.424783. almost 40 pixels difference is a lot, isn;t it?